# Pound sign (#) not working in PHP

Tags: php, get

I have variable 'cno' and it's values sometimes have `123#` - ( end with pound sign. )

The problem is, after passing the URL I couldn't get variable with pound sign.

ex: my url - `/index.php?cno=34#`

So I need to get `$_GET['cno']` value like = `34#`, but it only display **34**

Is it  possible to get 'cno' variable value with pound sign.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to encode the `#` as `%23`, so your URL would look like this:

> /index.php?cno=34%23

To make it easier use PHP's built-in `urlencode` function: http://php.net/urlencode

```
$cno = "34#";
$url = urlencode("/index.php?cno=" . $cno); // "/index.php?cno=34%23"
```

Comment: i have some variable values with # sign. (ex: A3XER#) so i need to pass this variable via URL.

Comment: @Prabath - Not sure I understand what your problem is, but I've updated my answer. Take a look...

Answer (score 5):

`#` in a URL indicates a document fragment. [URL-encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your values before sending them.

Comment: And to provide some information: [PHP: urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) and [HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)