# How to eliminate special characters from url?

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters

I have the following url where var_a should always be a number. Also I don´t know how many var_a will be:

http://localhost/url.php?var_a[]=298&var_a[]=299

How to prevent getting an error if the user writes special characters in the url?

I have done this:

```
$data =  preg_replace('/[^0-9\']/', '',$_GET['var_a']);
$data = str_replace("'", '', $data);

print_r ($data);// Array ( [0] => 298 [1] => 299 )
//This is ok, all number were printed
```

But I still get an error with the special characters like # % &

e.g.

http://localhost/url.php?var_a[]=298&var_a[]=#299

```
print_r ($data);// Array ( [0] => 298 [1] => )
//299 was not printed!
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't fix it if the users are entering the values directly in the URL.  The reason being is that these characters have special meanings in URLS: # represents data fragment, % represents unicode values, and & represents a new variable .  The two options you can do are to use if it is coming from a form is to use $_POST values, or use urlencode before submitting the values.  [Pound sign (#) not working in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479638/pound-sign-not-working-in-php) has more information on using urlencode .

Comment: var_a is coming from a form but $_POST is not an option. Is it possible to use urlencode with a form?

Comment: I don't believe you can use PHP's, but you can use Javascript's similar to how you would do a form validator.